# Should I create a new column before or after joining tables in Apache Spark using PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark

Should I create new column before or after join on Spark ?

I know that we should reduce tables before join to reduce the amount of data shuffled.
But is it a big difference between creating column before the join or after the join ?

withColumn().join()

versus

join().withColumn()

Comment: what kind of join are you performing? assuming that it's a join that would reduce the number of rows (e.g. not something like a crossjoin), then i think it should be more performant to join first because you are potentially dealing with less data after the join takes place

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.